# Why is 'clear:both' not working

Tags: html, css

I've just deleted some content off my home page, however mysteriously this seems to have mucked up my footer.

I've added the clear:both to the html and CSS but still can't seem to work.

Can anyone advise me of a fix?

You can see below in the first image how I want to footer to look! (floated, not on white with the same footer height and width as the old footer).

Thanks,

Sam

http://incomeprotectionstore.co.uk/images/old-footer.jpg

http://incomeprotectionstore.co.uk/images/new-footer1.jpg

Comment: Post your code not images

Comment: .clear {
    clear: both;
}

Comment: Can't add the code due to character limitation css file is held at /images/index.css

Comment: You don't have to add all of your code. Find out which parts are relevant, and include just those parts.

Comment: Please provide code example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/)

Comment: You are not supposed to just _dump_ you whole CSS here either – but rather provide an example with the minimal HTML and CSS code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Okay, here's the useful bit, you'll see the table closing tag to put it into prospective.

    </ul>
     </div>
           <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="footer">
   <p>FOOTER TEXT HERE</p>
   <p>IncomeProtectionStore.co.uk &copy; 2013 | <a href="index.php">Income Protection Insurance</a> | <a href="privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="terms.php">Terms and Conditions</a></p>
  </div>   
     </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I worked it out. All I needed was a div fest! Simply added two closing div tags and it closed the content (before the footer). Sorry I can't rep - don't have enough rep to rep! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You footer needs to be outside of your `wrapper_wrap` div. Then it works fine.

At the moment you have something like:

```
<div class="wrapper_wrap">
    <div class="wrapper">...</div>
    <div class="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

It needs to be like:

```
<div class="wrapper_wrap">
    <div class="wrapper">...</div>  
</div>
<div class="footer">...</div>
```

Please include code in your question, it makes it so much easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks, my code is already in a similar format:
    </ul> </div> <div style="clear: both;"></div> <div class="wrapper"> <div class="footer"> <p>FOOTER TEXT HERE</p> <p>IncomeProtectionStore.co.uk &copy; 2013 | <a href="index.php">Income Protection Insurance</a> | <a href="privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="terms.php">Terms and Conditions</a></p> </div> </div> </div> </body> </html>

Comment: Forget that last comment - I worked it out. All I needed was a div fest! Simply added two closing div tags (before the footer) and it closed the content. Thanks for your message it sorted me out! Sorry I can't rep - don't have enough rep to rep!